# Two divs going inside eachother

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, and I want to set them so the body div starts below the navbar, but they keep intersecting. How would I make it so that the bodyContainer div is always below the navbar?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <div id="topBarContainer">
        <div id="topBar">
            <span id="topBarTitle">Private & Air's Shop</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyContainer">
        <div id="bodyContent">
            <div id="mainBodyContent">
            test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

CSS: http://pastebin.com/u5Z4ib4q
The css was long, so I put it into a pastebin.

Comment: If I do that, when I try to add a margin to the top, then it does this http://prntscr.com/6xsxzz

Comment: Use JSFiddle, it's easy to see and experiment with your html/css that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used 'position:fixed'  on #topBarContainer in the css. This means that when other elements on the page are to take their positions, they will completely ignore the #topBarContainer  as if it was not there in the first place. So remove 'position:fixed' from the css file. if however you chose to use 'position:fixed' intentionally to maintain the position of#topBarContainer even when the page is scrolled up then you should add the following to #bodyContainer#topBarContainer to force it under the #topBarContainer div

position:fixed;
        top:75px;

Comment: L messed things up a bit. Pls add the following to #mainBodyContent position:fixed; top:75px;

Answer (score 0):

you have used fixed position #topBarContainer. So that you need to add top-margin in body container

Comment: It still comes up like this prntscr.com/6xsxzz

Answer (score 0):

on your css

```
#bodyContainer {
     margin-top:50px;/*the height of your header*/
}
```

This should do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `position: fixed;` from your `#topBarContainer`, that will bring your `#bodyContainer` right below the navigation.

Optionally, I changed the `#topBar`'s `height: 75px;` into `min-height: 75px;`, so you won't lose the content on smaller viewports.

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9me3hob3/

Comment: Holy crap, thanks so much... I've been so annoyed about this & was about to quit.